# Proving the range of operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have a hard time understand (2) of the Fredholm alternative in Evan's Appendix.
[image]

To prove the image of $I-K$ is closed, what result from functional analysis is used? I am lost in understand the first sentence of the proof, up to equation (4). Could anyone explain to me what result in functional analysis is used? Which section in the relevant part of any functional analysis one shall study for?

I believe that the result, i.e. 
"The range of $K$ is closed iff there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\|Kx\|\ge c\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$ ($K$ is bounded below) is used. But I do not know if so, and where does this result come from, in functional analysis text.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general result you might be looking for is the following: Assume $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is a bounded injective operator between Banach spaces. Then $R(T)$ is closed if and only if there exists $c > 0$ such that $||Tx|| \geq c||x||$ for all $x \in X$.

In one direction, if there exists such a constant and $Tx_n \rightarrow y$ then $Tx_n$ is Cauchy but then the inequality $||Tx_n - Tx_m|| = ||T(x_n - x_m)|| \geq c||x_n - x_m||$ implies that $x_n$ is also Cauchy. Since $X$ is complete, $x_n \rightarrow x$ and since $T$ is bounded, $Tx_n \rightarrow Tx = y$ and so $y \in R(T)$.

In the other direction, if $R(T)$ is closed then $T \colon X \rightarrow R(T)$ is a bounded bijective operator between Banach spaces and so by the inverse mapping theorem, it has a bounded inverse $T^{-1} \colon R(T) \rightarrow X$ and so there exists $d > 0$ such that $||x|| = ||T^{-1}(T(x))|| \leq d ||Tx||$ for all $x \in X$ and we can take $c = \frac{1}{d}$.

In your case, $T = I - K$ and $X = N(T)^{\perp}, Y = H$.

Comment: The general result you mean, is the bounded inverse theorem, right? Also, I do not quite get what you mean by inverse mapping theorem.

Comment: From what I could understand from your post, it seems you are missing the equivalence between closed image and boundness from below for injective maps - this is what I called "the general result". The proof uses a result that is called by different people in different names - inverse mapping theorem, bounded inverse theorem, (corollary of the) open mapping theorem and various other different names. It states that a bijective bounded linear map between Banach spaces has a bounded inverse.

Comment: Still not getting what you mean. Perhaps I should study open mapping theorem then see what can be deduced.

Comment: I thought that it might be useful to give you some context. A theorem whose proof I provided here states that if you want to show that an injective operator $T \colon X \rightarrow Y$ has closed range, you can show instead that it is bounded from below. One direction of the proof is trivial and the other direction uses the bounded inverse theorem. In your case, you have an operator $I - K$ and you want to show its range is closed. It might not be injective, but if you restrict it to $N(I-K)^{\perp}$, it will be an injective bounded map with the same range.

Comment: Thus, the theorem might motivate you to show instead that $I - K$ restricted to $N(I - K)^{\perp}$ is bounded from below and this is what Evans does using the compactness of $K$. Finally, the direction that Evans needs is "bounded below => closed image" which doesn't use the open mapping theorem so you don't need to study it to understand the proof. I just thought it would be useful to say that this is an if and only if condition.

Comment: going through your comments slowly...on "It might not be injective, but if you restrict it to $N(I−K)^{\perp}$, why? restrict to $N(I−K)^{\perp}$ will make it injective?I do not get this, I do not know the theory behind for this idea.

Comment: Set $T = I - K$. If $Tv = Tw$ then $T(v - w) = 0$. But if $v,w \in N(T)^{\perp}$ then this implies that $v - w \in N(T) \cap N(T)^{\perp} = \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: I believe that having a bound from below implies that $T$ is injective. Let $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator between two Banach spaces, then 1 is equivalent to 2, where 1. $T$ is injective and $R(T)$ is closed; 2. there is a $c>0$ for which $\|Tx \| /\|x\| \ge c$ for all $x$.  The argument is that, suppose that $T$ is not injective, i.e. there is $x_0\not=0$ but $Tx_0=0$, then $x_0$ would violate the lower bound $c$.

Answer (score 0):

We prove the first estimate (1) $||u - Ku|| \geq \gamma ||u||$ $\forall u \in N(I-K)^\perp$ and for some $\gamma >0$. Reasoning by contradiction we have that $\exists \lbrace u_n \rbrace \subset N(I-K)^{\perp}$ such that $||u_n||=1$ and $(\star)$ $||u_n - K u_n || < 1/n$, by $(\star)$ we have $||u_n - Ku_n|| \rightarrow 0$ and also $||u_{n_j} - Ku_{n_j}|| \rightarrow 0$, therefore

$||u_{n_j} - u || \leq ||u_{n_j} - K u_{n_j}|| + ||K u_{n_j} - u || \rightarrow 0$

also $||K u_{n_j} - Ku || \rightarrow 0$, since $K:H \rightarrow H$ is continuos, and then $Ku=u$, i.e. $u \in N(I-K)$, but $u \in N(I-K)^\perp$ implies $u=0$ necessarily, this is a contradiction because $||u_n|| = 1$.

Now, let $\lbrace v_n \rbrace \subset R(I-K)$ such that $||v_n - v|| \rightarrow 0$, by definition $\exists \lbrace u_n \rbrace \subset H$ such that $u_n - Ku_n = v_n$ with $\lbrace u_n \rbrace \subset N(I-K)^\perp$, since if $u_n \in N(I-K)$ then $v_n=0$.
By (1):

$|| v_n -v_m || = ||(u_n -u_m) -K(u_n - u_m) || \geq \gamma ||u_n - u_m||$

since $\lbrace v_n \rbrace$ is of Cauchy, also $\lbrace u_n \rbrace$ is of Cauchy, and $|| u_n - u || \rightarrow 0$, but $I-K$ is continuous and $u-Ku=v \in R(I-K)$. So $R(I-K)$ is a closed.